# Javascript Object Model REST/AJAX: does callback/resulting function have access to the id of newly created item

Tags: list, javascript, client-object-model, jquery, rest

so if I use rest like method to create a list item in javascript, can I get the id of the newly created item in the callback/result function?

```
function createNewRecord(url, body, callback)
{
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: url,
         contentType: 'application/json',
         processData: false,
         data: body,
         success: function () {  callback(); }  
    });
}   

function createAnItem() {

  newItem = {};
  newItem.Title = 'Hello World';
  var body = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(newItem);
createNewRecord(urlVariable, body, onNewItemCallback);

}

function onNewItemCallback() {
     //is the id of the created item available here?
}
```

thanks! like response, response.get_responseData() from a GET request...or something like that?

Comment: as far as I have been able to find anywhere, it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from the POST message contains a JSON object representing the item that was just created. A reference to this object is passed as part of the first parameter to the success callback.

```
function createItem() {
    var due = new Date();
    due.setDate(due.getDate() + 7); // seven days from today

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Tasks')/Items",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.TasksListItem" },
            Title: "Sample Task",
            AssignedToId: _spPageContextInfo.userId,
            DueDate: due
        }),
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var itemId = data.d.Id;  // Id of new item

            var message = jQuery("#message");
            message.text("Item added. Id = " + itemId);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton Rob. saved me a bunch of GETs as I was just unaware that each time I used this, the Id was already coming back :)